# Call post ID in Javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to call the post ID in a script

```
<?php the_id() ?>
```

here :

```
$.get('', 'wpfpaction=add&postid=350');
```

I tried this but it's not working

```
$.get('', 'wpfpaction=add&postid='<?php the_id() ?>'');
```

Actually, my first goal was to do this action : wpfpaction=add&postid=350 which is usually in an url without load any url. Just to call the action.

Comment: no idea what you are asking, but maybe `<?php echo the_id() ?>` needs an echo??????

Comment: I think you need to do `echo the_id();`.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID Acording to the wordpress codex, id in the_id function is upper case, plus it echoes the id, doesnt returns it.

Comment: You should generally use an external script for added javascript, and use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass data from Wordpress to your javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your javascript syntax to echo php variable into it.

```
$.get('', 'wpfpaction=add&postid=<?php the_ID() ?>');
```